# Как можно реализовать перегрузку оператора &?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Определить операции над
массивами: & формирование нового массива так, что каждый элемент
нового массива определяется следующим образом:
c[i]=(a[i]>b[i])?a[i]:b[i];
Проблема в том, что понятия не имею как это реализовать. И ещё с размерностью массива проблемы возникают

Comment: язык программирования-то какой?

Comment: на с++ нужно сделать

Comment: похожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67771901/template-class-conversion-with-two-parameters/67772083#67772083